# Error: Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

I started using Angular and now I am stuck with the following problem...

When I load log-in page, in firebug console I am getting:

`Error: Unknown provider: loggerProvider <- logger.....`

If anyone can look this very small project angular-seed-master.zip, which can be downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/3rm7nvp825xoydgowg3p).

It contains basic log-in, log-out, register functionality.

Somehow, in login.js `RootCtrl` function, I am not allowed to pass logger as a parameter. I don't know why.

Thank you very much,
Danijela

Snippet:

Peace of login.js controller:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, logger, messagesService) {    
}

function RootCtrl ($scope, $http, logger, $location) {
...
}

function UnsecureCtrl ($scope) {
...
}
```

Peace of index.html:

```
...
<body>
    <div ng-controller="RootCtrl">
    <header>
        <div class="user-panel">
            <div ng-switch on="isLoggedIn">
                <div class="user" ng-cloak ng-switch-when="true">Hello {{email}}!</div>
                <div class="loginout">
                    <button class="btn" ng-cloak ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="loginRoute()">Login</button>              
                    <button class="btn" ng-cloak ng-switch-when="true" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'view-enter'}"></div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

and main.js:

```
'use strict';

require.config({
    baseUrl:'js',
    paths:{
        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min',
        angular: '../lib/angular/angular.min',
        toastr: '../lib/toastr.min',
        logger: 'components/logger',
        loginctrl: 'controllers/login',
        securectrl: 'controllers/secure',
        messagesService: 'services/messagesService',
        ngLoginSubmit: 'directives/ngLoginSubmit'
    },
    shim:{
        'angular':{
            exports:'angular'
        },
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'toastr': {
            deps:['jquery'],
            exports: "toastr"
        },
        'routes': {
            deps:['loginctrl','securectrl']
        },
        'logger': {
            deps:['jquery','angular','toastr']
        },
        'ngLoginSubmit': {
            deps:['angular']
        }
    },
    priority:[
        'angular'
    ]
});

require([
    'angular',
    'jquery',
    'loginctrl',
    'securectrl',    
    'app',
    'toastr',
    'logger',
    'routes',
    'messagesService',
    'ngLoginSubmit'
], function (angular) {
    //After all dependencies are loaded, bootstrap application
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['tableplanner']);
    });
});
```

and logger.js:

```
'use strict';
define(['app', 'toastr'], function (app, toastr) {

    app.factory('logger', function () { 
    ...
```

Comment: Did you include the script on the page

Comment: Please add code in your question if possible

Comment: Do you need anything else please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that logger was properly injected. Add a snippet to help you, it's better than linking a whole project.

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer, I just add the snippet. Do you need any other information?

Comment: Logger is properly injected in LoginCtrl but seams not in RootCtrl.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed ng-app attribute from html tag and with this problem was solved.